# Could I combine "eaves-" (doing something stealthily) with other action?

Tags: prefixes

As far as I know, I only know two words have "***eaves-***" that means "*to doing something stealthily*" — "*eavesdrop*" and "*eavesread*".

> eavesdrop ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eavesdrop))
>
> *"... purposefully trying to hear the conversation of others."*
>
> eavesread ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eavesdrop))
>
> *"to surreptitiously read something."*

Could I combine **eaves-** with other action like *eavesmove* to give meaning of *"move (slow/fast) stealthily*"?

Comment: Never heard of "eavesread"; and while there is nothing preventing you from coining words beginning with *eaves-*, you are unlikely to have much success getting people to recognize your meaning easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My answer is No.

If you did, no-one would understand what you meant unless you explained it.  The only instance of 'eavesread' I could find was Urban Dictionary, a notoriously unreliable source.  It is possible that this particular word may gain acceptance with the online community but it will only happen through widespread acceptance. There is no formula to create further such words.

There is nothing surreptitious about the word 'eaves' nor is there about the word 'drop'. It is only the combination that makes sense.

> eaves /iːvz/
>
> the part of a roof that meets or overhangs the walls of a building.
> "wild bees nest under the eaves"
>
> Google Dictionary

The term eavesdrop is explained here:

> eavesdropper (n.) mid-15c., with
> agent-noun ending + Middle English eavesdrop, from Old English
> yfesdrype "place around a house where the rainwater drips off the
> roof," from eave (q.v.) + drip (v.). Technically, "one who stands at
> walls or windows to overhear what's going on inside."
>
> [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=avesdrop&searchmode=none)

Note that *"one who **stands** at walls or windows **to overhear** what's going on inside."* has no relation to  your *"**move** (slow/fast) **stealthily**".*

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what are you asking?

If you are asking, "If I were to invent words using 'eaves' to indicate stealth, would most people immediately understand what I was saying?" the answer is that it depends on context and just how you did it, and who you hang out with, but I suggest that most people would get tired of it pretty quickly, and it certainly would not be considered standard English.

On the other hand, if you're asking "Is there any overwhelming reason I can't invent such words, knowing in advance that some people will object to non-standard vocabulary, and others won't understand what I'm saying without explanation", the answer is a ringing "No". That's one of the characteristics of English - anybody can invent their own words, and if enough others find the new words useful and start using them, they will eventually be accepted as standard English. Although there will obviously be a transition period.

In other words, such words are perfectly cromulent.

Answer (score 0):

I did a corpus search in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and [iWeb](https://www.english-corpora.org/iWeb/) for `eaves*` and looked at the top results (capped at 100 in iWeb). I found almost nothing. There's a single relevant result (from COCA) citing the San Francisco Chronicle, which in turn is citing [Enlightenment Through Eavessharing](https://www.macworld.com/article/174892/eavessharing.html):

> And because I am, I would like to thank Apple for implementing music sharing in iTunes—the process by which you can listen to someone else’s iTunes music library if that person has switched iTunes’ music sharing feature on and the two of you are on the same network subnet. Oh sure, this is a handy enough feature around the house when I want to listen to music stored on one of my computers without actually having to sit down at that particular machine. But here at the South By Southwest conference, this feature has opened up a whole new world of eavesdropping—or ***eavessharing*** , if you will. It’s like this:
>
> I’m sitting in my hotel room, whiling away the hours before this afternoon’s panel with Elvis Costello. I’m jacked into the hotel’s broadband system in order to get my work done. I launch iTunes to find some appropriate music to accompany my keyboard tapping and lo, a couple of shared music libraries appear in the Source list. Just for fun, I select one to see what my neighbors are listening to.

There are two reasons why this usage works here. The articles explain the meaning of the nonce word (though only Macworld makes an explicit connection to *eavesdropping*), and it also really isn't using the word all that differently from the original *eavesdropping*, since both refer to someone secretively getting private information from someone else (whereas "eavesmove" is quite unintelligible to me).